# Reordering entries of integer symmetric matrix via linear combinations into a symmetric matrix with all its eigenvalues positive with det condition

Tags: computational-number-theory, integer-matrices

Suppose we have a symmetric matrix $M\in\operatorname{Sym}{M}_{n}(\mathbb{Z})$ having some negative eigenvalues. Are there algorithms filling the entries of a (possibly) bigger symmetric matrix $M'\in\operatorname{Sym}{M}_{m}(\mathbb{Z})$ whose entries $M'_{i,j}$ are obtained with the same formula for all cases (that is, uniformly for any example) as integer (that is, with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$) linear combinations of the entries in the original matrix $M$ such that the eigenvalues of this new and possibly bigger symmetric matrix $M'$ are all positive (that is, the matrix is positive definite) and $\det(M)$ divides $\det(M')$?